# TableView cell background image issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have the following code to set my cell's background as an image:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 55)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBackground.png"];


cell.backgroundView = imageView;
```

but unfortunately the background image is cut to half, IDK why:

[image: This is how it looks]
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the default UITableViewCell then this should solve your problem:

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try like this ;

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 55)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBackground.png"];


cell.contentView.addSubView = imageView;
```

Or you can also try this ;

```
YourTableView.setBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Hope this will help